# SIM7080G GPS Module temporarily fails with PiFmRds

Tags: pi-zero, gps, radio, pifm

I have a SIM7080G GPS module for the Raspberry Pi Zero ([Product Wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM7080G_Cat-M/NB-IoT_HAT)), and the GPS it works fine (I am not using the cellular functionality).

I am trying to transmit radio (at the same time) using PiFmRds, but as soon as I start PiFmRds, the GPS Module fails and will not start until I restart the Pi.

I also tried other similar FM-transmitting programs but most wouldn't compile. I did however get "fm-transmitter" ([GitHub Page](https://github.com/markondej/fm_transmitter)) to compile and it worked with the GPS module!

I want to figure out why fm-transmitter works but PiFmRds doesn't. I need RDS for my project so if there are any other programs or suggestions that may work for me, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me it seems your GPS module works while PiFmRds is not running and PiFmRds runs while GPS is not working. Did you considered that whatever broadcasting solution you are using is blocking your (and possibly god knows what else) GPS? Seems by a quick search that is some kind of hacky rf broadcasting, that i believe is illegal. Do you have license to broadcast? If no, perhaps different radio solution would be more suitable.